# Website Description not showing in Google search engine

Tags: robots.txt

My website description not showing in Google search engine.

I wrote description meta tag inside the header tag.

and my robots.txt file as below

```
User-agent: *
Disallow: /
```

When i am searching in google i am getting below message
A description for this result is not available because of this site's robots.txt – learn more.

Comment: You told Google not to look at your page. Now it can't see something you wrote on the page. Why are you surprised? "Doctor, doctor, it hurts when I do this!" "So don't do that".

Comment: But why google search engine not showing my website description, any solution to this

Comment: Your website description is embedded in a page you forbade Google from reading!

Comment: Ok, please give me solution to this

Comment: "Doctor, doctor, it hurts when I do this!" **"So don't do that"**

Answer (score 2):

```
User-agent: *
Disallow: /
```

## You're blocking all robots to crawl your website.

---

Simply remove that line to enable robots to crawl your site, or use:

```
User-agent: *
Disallow:
```

---

`robots.txt` examples:

**To exclude all robots from the entire server (what you have!)**

```
User-agent: *
Disallow: /
```

**To allow all robots complete access (or just create an empty "/robots.txt" file, or don't use one at all)**

```
User-agent: *
Disallow:
```

**To exclude all robots from part of the server**

```
User-agent: *
Disallow: /cgi-bin/
Disallow: /tmp/
Disallow: /junk/
```

**To exclude a single robot**

```
User-agent: BadBot
Disallow: /
```

**To allow a single robot**

```
User-agent: Google
Disallow:
```

---

Learn more about robots.txt at [http://www.robotstxt.org](http://www.robotstxt.org/robotstxt.html)

Comment: Thank you for your information. if i do changes and deployed in the server, then how much time it will take to display a description in search engine.

Comment: I'd say about a week, but honestly I don't  know.

Comment: You're very welcome @user3363965. If my answer helped you, please mark it as the correct answer, thank you !